# A PHP array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, class

I want to populate an array with objects..

my class:

```
class MyOrderClass {
public $id;
public $many;
public $cost;

public function __construct($id, $many, $cost) {

    $this->id = $id;
    $this->many = $many;
    $this->cost = $cost;

    }
}
```

and i want to have something like this :

```
$orders[0]->id = 1;
$orders[0]->many = 1;
$orders[0]->cost = 100;
```

can you help me ?

Comment: Not clear what you asking...

Comment: Can you explain how can i have an array of above class ?

Comment: What is your goal? What will you make with the array of objects ?
Give us more details so we can guide you.

Answer (score 3):

```
$orders = [];
$orders[] = new MyOrderClass(1, 1, 100);
$orders[] = new MyOrderClass(1, 2, 150);

// alternatively
array_push($orders, new MyOrderClass(1, 3, 200));

// contents of the array
var_dump($orders);
```

You just need to push the objects into an array

Answer (score 0):

you're saying you want to make an array from a class but you're code example is creating an array of objects so, if you want what your example is see the other answer, if you want what you actually asked for, you can just cast the object as array:

```
$order = new MyOrderClass(1, 1, 100);
$order = (array) $order;
var_dump($order);
```

https://3v4l.org/LF2ps

Comment: https://3v4l.org/72pS8

Comment: How can i check if current id exist ? above link

Comment: you're trying to turn your object into some kind of crazy object array inception thing.. what you're doing is ridiculous and doesn't make any sense.. you need to re-think you're strategy here..

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the first element of the array to be an instance of your class/object, and then change the properties:

```
$orders = [];
$orders[0] = new MyOrderClass();

$orders[0]->id = 1;
$orders[0]->many = 1;
$orders[0]->cost = 100;
```

Comment: And how can i access the all members is class like :for($i=0;$i<count($this);$i++)
    {
     if($this[$i]->id == $id)
     {
      $found=true;
      $this[$i]->many += $many;
      break;
     }
    }
    if (!$found)
    {
     $this->id = $id;
     $this->many = $many;
    }
  }

Comment: https://3v4l.org/72pS8

Comment: that is not how you change properties. (using `==`)

Comment: @Pamblam thanks it was bad copy-paste. Updated!